# Multiple left joins on multiple tables in one query find Employee Attendence Maximum and Minimum Value

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

Output shown like given below. I've got one master table, which has items stored in multiple levels, and there is a second table which may or may not have additional data. I need to query two levels from my master table and have a left join on my another table, but because of the ordering within my query this will not work.

```
hrm_personal_information (PBI_ID,Name,department_id,designation_id)
department (department _id,department _name)
designation(designation_id,designation_name)
access_event_logs(PBI_ID,TIMESTAMPS)    


User ID Name    Deapartment Designation Date    Day In Time Out Time    Working Hours
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   11/2/2015   Saturday    10:05:01    17:12:02    7:07
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   11/3/2015   Sunday  10:10:01    17:30:02    7:30
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   0000-00-00  Monday  0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   11/5/2015   Tuesday 10:00:01    17:10:02    7:10
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   0000-00-00  Wedday  0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   11/7/2015   Tharusday   10:05:01    17:05:02    7:00
100032  Farid Ahammad   Anesthesia  Senior Consultant   11/8/2015   Friday  10:05:01    17:12:02    7:07
```

my query is

```
SELECT a.PBI_ID as employee_id, 
concat(first_name," ",middle_name," ",last_name) as Name, c.DESG_DESC as designation, 
b.DEPT_DESC as department, 
e.BRANCH_NAME as work_place, 
date(TIMESTAMPS) as Date_on, 
DAYNAME(TIMESTAMPS) as days, 
min(time(TIMESTAMPS)) as in_time, `enter code here`
max(time(TIMESTAMPS)) as out_time, 
TIMEDIFF(max(time(TIMESTAMPS)),
min(time(TIMESTAMPS))) as hours, 
a.office_start_time as office_hours_from, 
a.office_end_time as office_hours_to, 
a.office_hours 
FROM 
hrm_personal_information a, 
department b, 
designation c, 
branch e, 
access_event_logs h
WHERE 1 and 
a.department = b.DEPT_ID and 
a.designation=c.DESG_ID and 
a.branch=e.BRANCH_ID and 
h.USERID=a.PBI_ID and 
h.USERID like "%100032%" and 
TIMESTAMPS between "2015-11-01" and 
"2016-06-05" 
group by DATE(h.TIMESTAMPS) 
order by h.TIMESTAMPS
```

Comment: If you have output like that, then surely you also have a query.

Comment: I am very week in mysql , please help me @GordonLinoff

Comment: Use proper JOIN syntax. Then get back to us.